# Is Skype4Java still being developed?

Tags: java, skype, telephony, skype4java

Looks like the [last release of this](https://developer.skype.com/wiki/Java_API) was back in 9/30/06.  Is there still active development going on?  Has anyone built a commercial-quality product on top of this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, all I know is that Skype4Java API is active for Skype 4.1 API. I don't think that the API has changed too much seeing that the Skype4Java API is still active.

Comment: Not yet, I've just checked the API I downloaded (can't remember when) and it's still matches with the JAR found on Skype.